# Read first record of array instead of first character in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, database, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 . I've saved some array in my database and when I try to read those arrays I just get a single character of it.

For example the array in database is `["one", "two"]` and when i write

```
@foreach ($xs as $x)
    <li>
           {{ $x->y[0] }}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

it will just show '[' instead of 'one'

in my migration file i did this :

```
$table->json('y');

and in my model i did this :
    protected $casts = [
        'y' => 'json',
    ];
```

and also in model i did try this :

```
 protected $casts = [
        'y' => 'array',
    ];
```

and in my controller i did something like this one to show data :

```
 public function showData(){
        $x = DB::select('select * from x');

        return view('home',['x'=>$x]);
    }
```

Comment: Please read how to create a [mre] so that we can see the actual code running.

Comment: Did you try to display `$x` only?

Comment: no sir i didnt try that. but im sure that when i use $x->y , ill get complete array.

Comment: What is the output of `dd($xs);` on your controller?

Comment: Could be you are passing JSON string instead array. `json_decode($xs)` before use as an array.

Comment: @sta its something like this :array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1183 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"status": ""
    +"odd": 2
    +"hosts": "["qwdwd","ddwww"]"
    +"guests": "["qwdqwd","wqwd"]"
    +"created_at": "2021-02-06 11:55:54"
    +"updated_at": "2021-02-06 11:55:54"
  }
]

Comment: Can you sharw the output as picture?

Comment: @sta here's the picture of output : https://pasteboard.co/JN6hPqC.png  the 'q' that u see in first line (above the black box) is $x->y[2]

Comment: You tried `$x->y[0]`, but  there are no any `y` property on your output

Comment: @sta you mean +"hosts": "["qwdwd","ddwww"]" is'nt what you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. the problem was the way that i've called the record on table.
I missed adding

```
use App\MyModel;
```

to my controller.
and in my controller i used to write

```
$x = DB::(select * from mytable);
```

which I changed it to :

```
$x= MyModel::all();
```